# jQuery Ajax request doesn't return data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a group of button, I want click each one, send data to a processing page, then return data to the `self html` and change class `click` to `more`.

In any case, my code have no reture data. I have checked in `chrome - network`, I can see the ajax process success, even add an alert in `success: function`, I also can get it. Where am I wrong?

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").live('click',function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            data: "add=ccc",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){ 
                //alert('success');
                $(this).html(data).addClass('more').removeClass('click');
            }
        });
    });
});

<a class="click">bbb</a>
```

add.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['add']; ?>
```

Comment: Fyi, you can use `data: {add: 'ccc'}` - it's cleaner and as soon as you start sending user input you won't have to take care about escaping.

Comment: So in your add.php, you're expecting it to return the string "ccc"?

Comment: try setting context in the ajax object.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, thanks for suggestion, still not work. I guess the problem in `$(this)`, but I really need it.

Comment: @Jacob, i have many link, each send itself data to another page, then return the data to `itself.html` with a calss change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` doesn't point to the link inside the success function.

Add `var self = this;` before the `$.ajax` call and use `self` instead of `this` inside the callback.

Another option would be using `context: this` in the `$.ajax` options.

Comment: It's not really strange. `this` is special in JavaScript and it'd be **impossible** for jQuery to preserve `this` inside that function.